# Error: Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to add scrolling to a Sencha Touch field set. While I am trying to scroll down the field set, it is showing the below error in logcat:

```
W/webview(1003): Miss a drag as we are waiting for WebCore's response for touch down.
```

For field set, i wrote the below code:

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    docked: 'top',
    margin: '20000',
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'consumername',
            style: 'font: DroidSans',
            label: 'ConsumerName',
            labelWidth: '30%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            id: 'Mobilenum',
            style: 'font: DroidSans',
            label: 'Mobile',
            labelWidth: '30%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            id: 'email',
            label: 'CustomerEmailid',
            labelWidth: '30%',
            placeHolder: 'email@example.com'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            id: 'adressfield',
            style: 'font: DroidSans',
            label: 'Address',
            labelWidth: '30%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            id: 'areafield',
            style: 'font: DroidSans',
            label: 'Area/Location',
            labelWidth: '30%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            label: 'City',
            labelWidth: '30%',
            options: [
                {
                    text: 'Bangalore',
                    value: 'first'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Delhi',
                    value: 'second'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Mumbai',
                    value: 'third'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            id: 'pinfield',
            style: 'font: DroidSans',
            label: 'Pincode*',
            labelWidth: '30%'
        },

    ]
}
```

I am testing in Android Olive Pad tablet with 2.2 version. I am using Sencha Touch 2 and PhoneGap to build the app.

Comment: http://uihacker.blogspot.ca/2010/10/android-bug-miss-drag-as-we-are-waiting.html